# How to load an accelerators map from a file using GTK3 in Vala?

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm making a text editor using GTK3 in Vala. I have a `Gtk.MenuBar` in a `Gtk.Window` and I want to use accelerators to easily activate its `Gtk.MenuItems`. But I want the user to be able to change the key combinations, so I'm loading the accelerators specifications from a file using the method `Gtk.AccelMap.load("accels")`. However, after calling this method, the accelerators are not loaded: the menu items don't have `AccelLabels` and are not activated when I press the key combinations. Here are the two files I'm working on. The first file contains a small version of my application (to show what I'm trying to do) and the second one is the accels file from which I load the accels specifications, and they must be in the same directory.

main.vala

```
// Compile me with: valac main.vala -o main --pkg gtk+-3.0
public class MyWindow: Gtk.Window {
    public MyWindow() {
    this.set_default_size(500, 500);

    var main_box = new Gtk.VBox(false, 0);
    this.add(main_box);

    var accel_group = new Gtk.AccelGroup();
    this.add_accel_group(accel_group);

    // Load the accelerators from the file
    Gtk.AccelMap.load("accels");

    // Create the action
    var quit_action = new Gtk.Action("file-quit", "Quit", "Quit the application", null);
    quit_action.activate.connect(()=>{
        Gtk.main_quit();
    });
    quit_action.set_accel_group(accel_group);
    quit_action.set_accel_path("<MyWindow>/File/Quit");

    // Menubar
    var menubar = new Gtk.MenuBar();
    main_box.pack_start(menubar, false, false, 0);

    var file = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label("File");
    menubar.add(file);

    var file_menu = new Gtk.Menu();
    file.set_submenu(file_menu);

    var quit_mi = (Gtk.MenuItem)quit_action.create_menu_item();
    file_menu.append(quit_mi);

    // Label
    var label = new Gtk.Label("My Window");
    main_box.pack_start(label, true, true, 0);

    this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
    }
}

int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);

    var win = new MyWindow();
    win.show_all();

    Gtk.main();
    return 0;
}
```

"accels" file

```
; main GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<MyWindow>/File/Quit" "<Control>q")
```

So, why is this not working? What do I have to do before or after loading the accel file?

PS: I don't want to use a `Gtk.UIManager`.

Comment: Have you tried loading the accelerator map _after_ creating and adding the menu item?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

See : https://docs.xfce.org/faq#keyboard_related
"
This functionality has been disabled since GTK3 which means that Xfce apps that have migrated to GTK3 (such as xfce4-terminal) do not support it.
Refer to specific app's documentation to learn how to configure its shortcuts.
"